# Implementing a minification-safe resolve function using AngularJS, ui-router and uiBreadcrumbs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an AngularJS app. I've gotten quite a bit done but am stuck trying to implement a resolve using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and [uiBreadcrumbs](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/uiBreadcrumbs). So here is the problem, how do I implement a resolve which can work well with magnification, the same way controllers are implemented? I have included sample code below for brevity from [uiBreadcrumbs](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/uiBreadcrumbs). Look at the last state home.userList.detail.

```
angular.module('yourModule').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: ...
                }
            },
            data: {
                displayName: 'Home'
            }
        })
        .state('home.usersList', {
            url: 'users/',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: ...
                }
            },
            data: {
                displayName: 'Users'
            }
        })
        .state('home.userList.detail', {
            url: ':id',
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: ...
                }
            },
            data: {
                displayName: '{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName | uppercase }}'
            }
            resolve: {
                user : function($stateParams, userService) {
                    return userService.getUser($stateParams.id);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's the same as you would do with a controller function

Comment: @aw04 thank you very much. I wasn't aware of that since I've only been using AngularJS for about 5 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the function in an array object just like a controller:

```
resolve: {
    user : [
                '$stateParams', 'userService',
        function($stateParams,   userService) {
            return userService.getUser($stateParams.id);
        }
    ]
}
```